# Separate controller and view from multiples queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have multiple MySQL queries and I need to separate them into Controller and View (CodeIgniter framework), how is that possible? See example of codes below:

For example:

```
$SQL_Cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE restaurant_id = '$restaurantID'");

while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_Cat))
{

    $CategoryID = $category['id'];

    echo $category['name'];
    if ($category['description'] != "") { 
        echo $category['description'];
    }

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = '" . $CategoryID . "'");
    while($item = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {          
        $item_name = $item['name'];
        echo $item_name;
        $item_des = $item['description'];
        $sq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_options WHERE item_id = '" . $item['id'] . "'");
        $item_id = $item['id'];
        if(mysql_num_rows($sq) > 0)
        {
            while($item_option = mysql_fetch_array($sq))
            {
               echo "---------<br />";
               $item_option_name = $item_option['option_value'];
               $item_option_price = $item_option['price'];
               $item_option_id = $item_option['id'];

               echo $item_name;
               echo $item_des;
               echo $item_option_name;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The echo's part should be in view (MVC).

Answer (score 1):

Well... The simplest way is this

controller.php

```
$id = $_GET[ 'id' ] ;
include_once 'model.php' ;
$content = getPage( $id ) ;
include 'view.php' ;
```

model.php

```
function getPage( $id ) {
    $result = mysql_query( 'SELECT content FROM pages WHERE id = ' . intval( $id ) ) ;
    $c = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ;
    return $c[ 'content' ] ;
}
```

view.php

```
<?= $content; ?>
```

Just type http://site/controller.php?id=1 in your browser (there should be en entry in you db of course)

A bit simplified but no fun in writing code scrolls :)

Comment: I understood your concept but that does not answer my question.

Comment: Why not? Collect all data you need in your controller and pass it to the view. This code is not much different from that from my example, just a bit more code. If you want it to be exactly like in professional frameworks you need to read some docs on Reflection, callbacks and build your own mvc structure. Actually there are a lot of ways to implement mvc architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the user guide. It really helped me understand MVC.

1. [Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)
2. [View](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)
3. [Controller](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Once you have a good understanding of using this pattern, decomposing what you have shouldn't be too hard.